# React - the value of state which depends on another state cannot be updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Step to reproduce**

1. After entering Codesandbox Console, you can see the initial value of `typeA` and `allTypes`.
   [image]
2. Click "Update type A" button
3. In Console, you can see the updated value of `typeA` and `allTypes`.
   [image]

**Expected Behaviour**
In `allTypes`, the value of field `typeA` should be `"different value"`.

**Actual Behaviour**
the value of field `typeA` still remain unchanged.

**Questions**

1. Why doesn't the value of field `typeA` update?
2. How to fix it?

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [typeA, setTypeA] = useState("01");
  const [typeB, setTypeB] = useState("abc");

  const [allTypes, setAllTypes] = useState({
    typeA: [typeA],
    typeB
  });
  console.log({ typeA }); // updated successfully
  console.log({ allTypes }); // the value of typeA remain unchanged
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setTypeA("different value");
        }}
      >
        Update type A
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-lichterman-w1kbph?file=/src/App.js

Comment: In your actual code, do you call `setAllTypes` anywhere? Does `allTypes` actually need to be state?

Comment: The value passed in `useState()` is initial value. You will have to create a useEffect on `typeA` and set allTypes in it [Updated Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-wilbur-4ybtt7?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Rajesh as allTypes is a calculated value, avoid useEffect in favor of useMemo. This is almost the exact case described in the React "You might not need an effect" documentation https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument of useState is an initializer which doesn't update beyond the initial render. You can `useMemo` to achieve your intended behavior. You can't "feed" a value into the argument of useState.

```
const [typeA, setTypeA] = useState("01");
const [typeB, setTypeB] = useState("abc");

const allTypes = useMemo(() => {
   return {typeA: [typeA], typeB}
},[typeA, typeB])
```

You can do it without useMemo as well, but the object reference will be recreated every render.